# if div class is empty (using laravel foreachloop)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Here I have a foreach loop of teachers with their associated relationships which are reviews. As I loop through the teacher if they have no relationship or review I want to print "No Reviews" in the containing div. The code i use now works, however if one teacher has a review the other classes remain empty instead of saying No Review. Is there a way in laravel or in js i can do this? It's probably a simple solution for this. Can someone help me out?

**HTML:**

```
 @foreach($teachers as $teacher)
      <div class="item{{{ $isFirst ? ' active' : '' }}}">
          <div class = "deck">
               <div class = "row marg">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                         <div class = "stdnt">
                              <h1>Teacher Info</h1>
                              {!! Form::model( $student, ['url' => ['tchUpd', $teacher->id], 'method' => 'post', 'role' => 'form'] ) !!}
                               <h1>{{ucwords($teacher->name)}}</h1>
                                <div class = "form-group fga">
                                      {!!Form::label('title', 'NickName:', ['class' => 'control-label lad']) !!}
                                      {!!Form::text('nick', $teacher->nick, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina'])!!}
                                </div>
                                <div class = "form-group fga">
                                      {!!Form::label('title', 'Email:', ['class' => 'control-label lad']) !!}
                                      {!!Form::text('email', $teacher->email, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina'])!!}
                                 </div>
                                 <div class = "form-group fga">
                                        {!!Form::label('title', 'Position:', ['class' => 'control-label lad']) !!}
                                        {!!Form::text('pack', $teacher->position, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina'])!!}
                                 </div>
                                 <div class = "form-group fga">
                                        {!!Form::label('title', 'Bio-Short:', ['class' => 'control-label lad']) !!}
                                        {!!Form::text('short', $teacher->short, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina'])!!}
                                  </div>
                                  <div class = "form-group fga">
                                          {!!Form::label('title', 'Prof/Edu:', ['class' => 'control-label lad']) !!}
                                          {!!Form::text('profedu', $teacher->profedu, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina'])!!}
                                  </div>
                                  <div class = "form-group fga">
                                        {!!Form::label('title', 'Interests:', ['class' => 'control-label lad']) !!}
                                        {!!Form::text('interest', $teacher->interest, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina'])!!}
                                  </div>
                                  <div class = "form-group fga">
                                       {!!Form::label('title', 'Pitch:', ['class' => 'control-label lad']) !!}
                                       {!!Form::text('why', $teacher->why, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina'])!!}
                                  </div>
                                  <div class = "form-group fga">
                                       {!!Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=> 'btn btn-danger form-control'])!!}
                                   </div>
                                   {!! Form::close() !!}
                               </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "col-md-4">
                                 <div class = "teac">
                                      <h1>Teacher Info</h1>
                                          <div id = "user-profile" class = "addyphoto" style = "background-image: url(/assets/image/{{$teacher->photo}})">                                                                                                     </div>
                                          {!! Form::model( $student, ['url' => ['tchUpd', $teacher->id], 'method' => 'post', 'role' => 'form', 'novalidate' => 'novalidate', 'files' => true] ) !!}
                                          <div class = "form-group fga">
                                                 {!!Form::label('title', 'Picture:', ['class' => 'control-label lad']) !!}
                                                 {!!Form::text('photo', $teacher->photo, ['class'=> 'input-mini ina tch'])!!}
                                          </div>
                                          <div class = "form-group fga">
                                                {!! form::file('newphoto', null) !!}
                                                {!!Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=> 'btn btn-danger form-control'])!!}
                                            </div>
                                         {!! Form::close() !!}
                                     </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "mask flow">
                               <div class = "row-fluid marg reviewblock">
                                       @foreach($teacher->reviews as $review)
                                             <div class = "ablock">
                                                   <h1>{{ucwords($review->title)}}</h1>
                                                   <p>{{$review->created_at}}</p>
                                                       <p>{{$review->title}}</p>
                                                            <p>{!!$review->description!!}</p>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                   @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                       {{--*/ $isFirst = false; /*--}}
                                                    </div>
```

**JS**

```
if ( $('.reviewblock').children().length == 0 ) {
    $(this).append("<div class = 'empty'><h1>No Reviews</h1></div>");
}
```

/--------------second attempt ---------/

```
if (isEmpty($('.reviewblock'))) {
        $('.reviewblock').append("<div class = 'empty'><h1>No Reviews</h1></div>");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code will do it only for the first occurrence of the class ".reviewBlock". Do it for all the occurrences.

```
$('.reviewblock').each(function(i, obj) {
    if (isEmpty(this))) {
        $('.reviewblock').append("<div class = 'empty'><h1>No Reviews</h1></div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: He just asked laravel or js. I just gave my opinion on JS since you've done it in laravel.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is chekc if the variable is empty

```
<div class = "row-fluid marg reviewblock">
@if (empty($teacher->reviews))
    <div class = 'empty'><h1>No Reviews</h1></div>
@else
    @foreach($teacher->reviews as $review)
    <div class = "ablock">
        <h1>{{ucwords($review->title)}}</h1>
        <p>{{$review->created_at}}</p>
        <p>{{$review->title}}</p>
        <p>{!!$review->description!!}</p>
    </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
</div>
```

NOTE: Ah I forgot, remove all of the JS that you use to append HTML, you don't need that. Also would advise you not to use `<H1>` tag to style you page, this should be used only once on each page and that normally goes to the title/header of the page, otherwise Google might penalise you.

Comment: Still not printing anything? Maybe switch the if and the else statements?